# Run-time error '52' in VBA, Bad filename or number

Tags: vba

I am getting this error on VBA:
"Run-time error '52': Bad filename or number"

When I run the debugger, it highlights the line of the Dir function.

```
Dim ExcelPath As String, PDFPath As String

'Check if folders exist

ExcelPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("Excel_Folder").Value
PDFPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("PDF_Folder").Value

If Dir(ExcelPath, vbDirectory) = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Or Dir(PDFPath, vbDirectory) = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "The Excel & PDF folders do not exist. Please create these in the same folder as this workbook first.", vbInformation, "Folder does not exist"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Are both cells populated at the time?

Comment: I see rumblings on line that this error is thrown sometimes with OneDrive synced folders or network folders.

Comment: Is `ThisWorkbook.Path` a regular file path, or an http path?